# Variable passed into a preprocess function has incorrect data or or an unexpected format

Tags: theming, hooks

I wanted to change some of the forum’s topic's preprocessing. So I copied [`template_preprocess_forums()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21forum%21forum.module/function/template_preprocess_forums/8.4.x) into a custom module (*myModule*), and renamed the function `myModule_preprocess_forums()`.

I get an error that a method cannot be used on a string, `$topic`. I inspected. When the code is looping through the array `$variables['topics']`, it expects each array item to be an object.  However, in `$variables['topics']` there are items that are strings and arrays and no topic objects.

To debug, I inspected `$variables['topics']` in the Forums module, but all the  items are objects, as expected.

Why would the values passed to `myModule_preprocess_forums()` differ from what `template_preprocess_forums()` implemented by the Forums module gets?

Comment: Assuming _I copied this function into it_ didn't include the function body (or even if it did in some ways actually), I think you're falling victim to an annoying bit of code. I don't know if it's intentional for some reason so I hesitate to say it's a bug, but at the bottom of `template_preprocess_forums` is: `$variables['topics'] = $table;`, replacing the var with a render array (the one you're haplessly looping over), and removing the original objects from any scope you have access to in your own preprocess. There might be a way around it but it would be messy

Comment: @Clive you are correct! Thanks. Since this function is a 'hook' and is designed expecting the data to be passed through by reference I want to call this a bug. Changing the markup of that table format is exactly what we wanted to do and cannot as we don't have the original data to loop through. As you said, it would be messy to deconstruct the html table.  I will take this to the official issue queue and see what the response is. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, There was an issue in the queue already. I didn't find it on my initial search. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2890049

Answer (score 0):

It happens because [`template_preprocess_forums()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21forum%21forum.module/function/template_preprocess_forums/8.6.x), which is executed before any `hook_preprocess_forums()` implementation, overrides `$variables['topics']` with the render array for its table.

It would have been better to put the render array in a different array value. As you notice from the function code, starting from Drupal 8.6.x, the original value of `$variables['topics']` is available in `$variables['topics_original']`.

```
  $variables['topics_original'] = $variables['topics'];
  $variables['topics'] = $table;
  $variables['topics_pager'] = [
    '#type' => 'pager',
  ];
```